# Can't get autokey to work

Tags: apt, python, pip, dbus, autokey

After installing autokey I tried to run it by:

```
autokey-gtk
```

But I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/autokey-gtk", line 20, in <module>
    from autokey.gtkapp import Application
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/gtkapp.py", line 18, in <module>
    import common
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/common.py", line 19, in <module>
    import os.path, dbus.service
ImportError: No module named dbus.service
```

So I fixed it and got some more problems and I fixed them by:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center python-dbus
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-gi
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-xlib
```

Now the error I get is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/gtkapp.py:24: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GObject, GLib
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/gtkui/notifier.py:19: PyGIWarning: Notify was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Notify
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/gtkui/notifier.py:28: PyGIWarning: AppIndicator3 was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import AppIndicator3
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/gtkui/configwindow.py:20: PyGIWarning: GtkSource was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('GtkSource', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, Pango, GtkSource, Gdk, Gio
```

But I have no idea how to fix it! does anyone have any idea what should I do now?